# Problema em tabuada em C

Tags: c

Alguem sabe me dizer o porque o looping não estáa funcionando corretamente?

Era pra imprimir a tabuada de 0 a 10, mas ao invés disso ele está imprimindo numero digitado * 11.

Segue o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
int numero, cont=0;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    for (cont=0; cont<=10 ; cont++);
        {
        printf("%d x %d = %d \n",numero,cont,numero*cont);
        }
return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tira o `;` da frente do for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da forma que está o `printf` só é exibido uma vez após o contador sair do laço de repetição, ou seja, quando o cont possuir valor igual a 11. Para corrigir basta você remover o **;** que está após o `for()`.

Segue como deveria ficar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
int numero, cont=0;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    for (cont=0; cont<=10 ; cont++){
        printf("%d x %d = %d \n",numero,cont,numero*cont);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nao sabia dessa,muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Tinha um `;` depois do `for`, logo ele não executava nada e pulava direto para:

```
printf("%d x %d = %d \n",numero,cont,numero*cont);
```

Executando uma unica vez.
Segue código corrigido.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)

{
int numero, cont=0;

    printf("Digite um numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero);

    for (cont=0; cont<=10 ; cont++)
        {
        printf("%d x %d = %d \n",numero,cont,numero*cont);
        }
return 0;
}
```